# Became lead developer - how to lead the team

Tags: software-industry, leadership

I became a lead developer on the project I am working on 15 months now in a small company. I got additional developer under me to help with development. This is new thing to me. So I want to learn.

Other people who are working with me are web designer(html, graphic design), 2 affiliate managers and marketing expert for our product.

I want to learn how to work with them in this position. Since I am the lead at this project, everyone is coming to me for each question and since I still have to do the tasks by myself(core tasks), I need to find the way to be less interrupted by other people. Basically I don't want to be interrupted and defocused while I am working. When I am interrupted, I am less productive and have to work on weekends to finish my tasks by deadline and sometimes this makes me angry, but I don't want to be, because I don't need unnecessary stress.

Currently I am helping this new developer for each thing, but he is learning.

How do you manage other people in your team, which are expecting answers from you? Do you use spreadsheets for questions, bug errors?

I am already using spreadsheet for following the tasks done, because agile scrum is impossible in our company at the moment.

What other managing software would be helpful for me?

So how does first time lead developer on the project cope with questions, managing people in the way that it is possible for me to work as well and not be under-productive because of interruptions?

Second question.

As a lead developer I am in constant communication with marketing expert, which I think he wants to have me on the rope like a dog. Which I don't mind, if I am not interrupted, because he knows what he is doing and I like his ideas. The problem is when they start working improper way, want to use the system improper way, or just use short-cuts in the process, with which I do not agree, since these kind of short-cuts are stressful for me and were shown in the past as mistakes.

So how do I stand by my word here and make them listen to me and make it proper way?

Comment: Right now your question is very broad, entire books could be filled trying to answer the questions you pose (leading people, working with non-technical co-workers, managing workload, etc). I think a better idea would be to find someone that can coach you on a regular basis.

Comment: You need to learn not to get upset - it is not going to help.  Maybe try a any time before 10AM is my programming time.  The first 3 hours is when I am fresh and get most of my work done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as 'too broad' because it asks several questions at once and should be split.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, your "team" is you and another developer, correct?

> Currently I am helping this new developer for each thing, but he is learning.

Stop doing this. The only way he/she will grow as a developer is to give them tasks to figure out. Even if they don't do a good job, circle back around in a code review and show them a better method. You are the lead on this project. You need to delegate the work.

> How do you manage other people in your team, which are expecting answers from you? Do you use spreadsheets for questions, bug errors?

Spreadsheets might work, but they are inefficient. For development [Github](https://github.com/) is great for tracking issues and leveraging pull requests. Here's how I do it:

1. Create an issue for a developer for a task to be completed, or bugfix.
2. They make commits in a new branch referencing this Github issue (e.g. '#324 Fixed xyz')
3. Developer submits pull request with detailed information.
4. Conduct quick code review by testing new code and talking with developer.

For project management use [Basecamp](https://basecamp.com/), [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira), or similar. This gives you a centralized location for communicating with managers and other departments. You can assign people TODO's and keep records of the conversations. Badger people to use your project management software/service instead of emails.

Hopefully that will give you a start on reclaiming your weekends and managing your time at work.

Comment: "Stop doing this."  fully agree.  If this "dev" needs their hand held for *every little thing* then it's time to go to your manager and ask for someone else.